# Using components to retrieve data without returning a layout in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

### What I'm ultimately trying to achieve

Requesting and retrieving data from a 3rd party API (Facebook Graph API) by encapsulating the request within its own component.

### My proposed attempt

1. Inside the component displaying the current layout, `main` create an instance of the data retrieving component, `fbRetrieveData` and asynchronously calls a `retrieve` function.
2. The `retrieve` function within the `fbRetrieveData` then gets the data, manipulates it as necessary and returns it back to the `main` component.
3. The `main` component then displays the data.

### What I'm struggling with

I've found articles on how to do this, such as [this one](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17), but they all seem to require that some layout is returned and/or that the retrieving component is called by being part of the layout.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: you can always return null for component (meaning nothing will be rendered)

Comment: Why do you want to use a component to retrieve just data, you can use a function. Or am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: @RaviRaj thanks for the answer. I want to use a component as I would like to abstract away this functionality from the layout component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, I have decided to just use a JavaScript class instead to avoid having to return null as previously proposed.